# Identify DNS queries that get resolved by HOSTS file

Tags: windows, dns, hosts-file

How can I identify DNS lookups that are resolved by my HOSTS file?

Over the past month or so, I've begun experiencing long delays involving content stored on SharePoint Online, affecting Word, Excel and OneNote. These applications will sometimes stop responding for 60-90 seconds when opening or saving the documents. Curiously, sometimes the documents open/save without any delay. The problem appears random and does not follow any specific document.

I think I've narrowed the cause down to my HOSTS file. I use a custom HOSTS file provided by [mvps.org](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/) to resolve the domain name of over 13,000 trackers and known-bad domains to 0.0.0.0. If I disable the HOSTS file the delays go away.

I've looked through the HOSTS file for anything related to Microsoft, Office 365, SharePoint, etc. and don't see anything suspicious.

I've spent time looking in [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see if it shows name resolution attempts but found nothing. [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) also only seems to show successful network connections. I enabled the DNS Client Events operational log but it has captured nothing relevant.

**How can I see DNS lookups attempted by an application which get resolved to `0.0.0.0`?**

Note: I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Comment: Well it's possible to see the queries and responses by enabling the "Operational" event log: SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client%4Operational.evtx (Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client/Operational).  I don't believe this will tell you if the response came as a result of the hosts file but you can see which process ID made the request.  If you run ipconfig /displaydns` it will show the host file entries as they are known to the cache and the TTL will by high.  Maybe you can use this information.

Comment: Helpful! I've enabled this log and will see what it can tell me. Running `ipconfig /displaydns` displays addresses in the cache plus the *entire* HOSTS file, regardless of whether the entries have been queried, so that's command's not useful.

Comment: Sadly, this log isn't capturing anything useful. @HelpingHand

Comment: If the 3008 event id in the above event log has the ProcessID (of the process making the request) and the QueryResult field, i.e. 0.0.0.0.  You can get the process ID of all queries where the QueryResult data is 0.0.0.0 which would have come from the hosts file?

Comment: That event ID isn't being logged, even if I intentionally access a host name that's contained in the HOSTS file.

Comment: Curious, this is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/Jf7KGL6  I am using Win 10 Pro - 10.0.18990 Build 18990. I thought that info would do it for you.

Comment: Yup, no such event is being logged when I access a name specified in hosts. It's possible that event was added after the Windows 7 family.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Interesting thought and I will try that. I'm doubtful the problem is due to the size of the hosts file. I've had one this size for many years without ill effect despite logging thousands of hours on the Internet. But I will try this as it could produce important clues.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT The host file must point to an IP address.